# Date Conversion and Trunc in R

Tags: r, date

I am new to R and I am struggling to convert and trunc the following date format:

`2017-01-21T00:00:00.0000000`

I want it to become a normal `Y-M-D` date format. 
How do I get rid of the timestamp?

Thanks!

Comment: This works for me. `as.Date('2017-01-21T00:00:00.0000000')` returns `#[1] "2017-01-21"`

Comment: thank you, very helpful! I feel very beginner... :)

Answer (score 4):

You may try the excellent `anytime` package:

```
anytime::anytime("2017-01-21T00:00:00.0000000")
#[1] "2017-01-21 CET"
```

In case you need it as date:

```
anytime::anydate("2017-01-21T00:00:00.0000000")
#[1] "2017-01-21"
```